# Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile for no rails project in Ruby Nitrouis IO

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I installed the gems for both `mysql2` and Active Record. When I run my code I get an error:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in` `rescue in spec': Specified 'my sql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
        from `/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
```

Here is my code:

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'active_record'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")

client.query("show databases").each do |db|
  p db
end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  databases: 'store_manager'
)
```

The error is saying I need to add my sql2 to my gemfile.  Where can I find it and is there anything I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Gemfile at the root of your project. This should allow you to use the mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 0):

For Active Record 4.2.4, you'll need to use the following version of the `mysql` gem:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.18"
```

Comment: I added mysql my gemfile.  I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Aaron: Please edit your question to include your Gemfile, and we'll have a look.